# Combining XML tags vis XSLT like in a 1:n relation

Tags: xml, xslt, tags, siblings

Perhaps somebody can help. I want to combine a XML tag with his siblings in a XSLT script. I have the following XML file. I want to combine the tag  with all occurrences of the tag . Here an example
XML-file:

```
<root>
    <row>
        <number>1</number>
        <pkz>aaa</pkz>
        <pkz>bbb</pkz>
    </row>
    <row>
        <number>2</number>
        <pkz>ccc</pkz>
        <pkz>aaa</pkz>
        <pkz>ddd</pkz>
    </row>
    <row>
        <number>3</number>
        <pkz>aaa</pkz>
        <pkz>yyy</pkz>
    </row>
</root>
```

The result should look like this:

```
<row>
    <number>1</number>
    <pkz>aaa</pkz>
</row>
<row>       
    <number>1</number>
    <pkz>bbb</pkz>
</row>
<row>           
    <number>2</number>
    <pkz>ccc</pkz>
</row>
<row>           
    <number>2</number>
    <pkz>aaa</pkz>
</row>
<row>           
    <number>2</number>
    <pkz>ddd</pkz>
</row>
<row>           
    <number>3</number>
    <pkz>aaa</pkz>
</row>
<row>           
    <number>3</number>
    <pkz>yyy</pkz>
</row>
```

Thanks in advance and BR,
WAM

Comment: How far did your own coding attempts get you? Did you e.g. manage to at least copy all `<pkz/>`s within `<row/>`s separatly, ignoring the `<number/>`s? Please show the  code which got you closest to your goal and then explain what is missing.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following XSL transformation to flatten your xml.

```
<xsl:template match="root">
    <root>
        <xsl:apply-templates/>
    </root>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="*[name()!='number']"/>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="row/*">
    <row>
        <xsl:copy-of select="../number"/>
        <xsl:copy-of select="."/>
    </row>
</xsl:template>
```